# Nodal Analysis Question

Tags: circuit-analysis, analysis

[image: This is how I approached the problem.]

[image]

I however do not see any wrong with my approach. But I am not getting the correct answer. Is there anything to do with grounding? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: How did you get an amperage for \$V_B\$? That's definitely wrong. I haven't looked through the rest yet to see what else is wrong.

Comment: @helloworld922 I didn't get you. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: In the very last line, you have \$V_B = -49.37 A\$.

Comment: In your first equation for node B, you have \$I_3 + I_4 + I_5 = 0\$ but your diagram shows \$I_3\$ flowing in to node B, while the other currents flow out. So that is a sign error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be consistent with your signs and assumptions.

In writing the KCL equation for node A, you defined it as

\begin{gather}
I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = 0
\end{gather}

where \$I_1\$, \$I_2\$, and \$I_3\$ are all leaving the node (consistent with the arrows in your diagram). However, then you immediately define

\begin{gather}
I_3 = \frac{V_B - V_A}{2k\Omega}
\end{gather}

This is the negative of the convention you just established. I would go through and double-check all of your signs and make sure they are consistent with each other. I can see similar issues in the KCL equations for the other nodes as well. You get lucky a few times by having a double negative cancel out your mistake, but this is just getting the correct answer for the wrong reasons.